# Comparing items in list with items in datatable

Tags: c#, list, datatable

This is my list:

```
 List<String> myItems = new List<String>();
```

and this is how I compare with items with items in datatable:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
     if (myItems[i].ToString().Trim().Equals(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim()))
  }
```

But application breaks if number of items doesn't match. For example in mylist there is 30 items, but in dt there is 35.

Comment: it will because you are comparing on indexes

Comment: Is there any other way to compare?

Comment: You could use Linq to perform a join between your list and the datatable

Comment: you are comparing on what basis your problem is not clear

Comment: If myItems has 10 items an dt has eleven, what do you want to do with the eleventh item in dt? You have nothing left in myItems to compare it with.

Comment: nothing, just to avoid that item.

Answer (score 1):

To find items in your list that is not exists in the datatable

```
Items.Except(datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>(columnIndex)));
```

Reverse the above statement for items in your datable that is not in your list

Answer (score 1):

You can use lowest count between list and dt for lopping. So you will not getting break in loop.

```
List<String> myItems = new List<String>();
int count = myItems.Count>dt.Rows.Count?dt.Rows.Count:myItems.Count; // it will give lowest count between them
```

Now use this count in loop

```
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
  {
     if (myItems[i].ToString().Trim().Equals(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString().Trim()))
  }
```